# Why cant a group member modify a file in a group he is part of?

Tags: linux, debian, file-permissions, groups

-edit- i figured it out. I needed to use `adduser username group` instead.

I added a user with the command

```
useradd -G myapp_user newusername
```

then i changed the group on the public folder that i want the user to access. Here is the line using `ls -l` I see the group has been set.

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 root myapp_user 4096 Jul  9 19:13 public
```

I cd into it and do it again to and i see files like the below with the group. I also see rwx on both the public folder and on the content inside the directory.

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root myapp_user   4403 Oct 10  2007 info.png
```

Then i login as the user and CD into the folder i wrote `touch a` and i got a permission error. I cant add, delete or do anything even though i see 775 is the permission. I also tried `useradd -G myapp_user newusername` to find the user is already part of the group

what am i missing? am i suppose to flush something before it takes effect? restart something? why cant the user modify anything in the public folder?

using putty and winscp. But right now just putty.

-edit- i wrote `id newusername` and got the below. Why isnt the groupname included?!

```
uid=1000(newusername) gid=1000(newusername) groups=1000(newusername)
```

Comment: Go ahead and put your edit in as an answer, then you can accept that.  Makes things a bit easier to follow when someone views the question.

Comment: Please do id -a newername so that all groups are visible.  From the basic output provided, it would appear that newusername does not have myapp_user as a group.

Between the group changes, I hope that you logged out and then logged in as the group membership is populated only at login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `adduser username group` instead

Answer (score 1):

You setup the groups correctly, but the user's list of groups is set when they first login, and won't normally ever be re-evaluated. If you make a change to a user's list of groups, you either need to log out and log back in, or you need to run the `newgrp` command.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `newusername` into the `myapp_user` group with `gpasswd -a newusername myapp_user`. You should close any open session for `newusername` and perform a new login for the new group to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

After using user274's answer: Have you set the folder permissions? You must set it for letting members modify items be modified by the owner, group members or everyone.

I suggest you to use an chmod calculator and after that, use the command below:

```
chmod -R XXX .
```

- "-R" is the flag for "Recursively set these permissions". Optional.
- "XXX" is the chmod you got on the calculator
- "." is the current directory. You can indicate replace it with your absolute path  where you can apply the permissions.

That way i could upload files with my username on SFTP to certain folder that i has no permission before. Beware: setting 7 for Everyone could be dangerous for your system, so use with this with security in mind.