# linux timestamp permission error with winscp

Tags: linux, debian, file-permissions, winscp, timestamp

I added a user to a group and set the file and dir content to 775. When i use winscp to modify a file it complains it cant set the timestamp bc of a permission error. But it is able to update the file i edit. Why? details on how i set the user is here but i dont think anyone needs to read it [Why cant a group member modify a file in a group he is part of?](https://serverfault.com/questions/159179/why-cant-a-group-member-modify-a-file-in-a-group-he-is-part-of)

Comment: What are the permissions and ownership on the directory the file is in?

Answer (score 4):

WinSCP tries to 'preserve time stamp' by default. Some unix systems do not like letting users that don't own a file to change permissions or timestamps even if they have write access, for some strange reason.

To fix this error I went to `WinSCP Options > Preferences > Transfer` then edited the `Default` and unchecked `Preserve timestamp`.

This, I believe, leaves you with the functionality that when a file is modified the timestamp is updated, which makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your directory has the wrong owner/group, though the file itself has. What WinSCP is probably complaining about is that it can't set the directory’s timestamp, which is normally also updated if you change a file in it.

Comment: I am logged in as root. Its tryint to set the time to the past to match the file on my FS rather then upload time.